# JSON adding unnecessary Curly Braces

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am creating a Discord bot using Discord.py. I have created a command that will update an external JSON file with a user-specified value. While testing the command I noticed that certain words, such as `tes`, will add an unnecessary curly brace at the end of the JSON file. This problem only occurs with certain words, most work without any issues.

**Python file**

```
import json
with open("./file.json", "r+") as file:
    f = json.load(file)
    file.truncate()
    f["key"] = "tes"
    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(f, file, indent = 4)
```

**JSON file**

```
{
"key": "tes"
}
}
```

I have tried using `f.update({"key": "tes"})` but there is no difference.

EDIT:
The problem was resolved by moving `file.truncate()` below `file.seek(0)`

Comment: You are overwriting the original file; if the output is shorter than the input, input characters near the end of file will remain in the output file. Write to a new file, or re-open the file and then write the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - I know you got this working, but your `file.truncate()` and `file.truncate()` are a little black-magic-ey, and not used very much which will make your code less idiomatic, and more difficult to maintain.

I think this would be cleaner if you used separate filehandles for the reading and writing to the file.

```
filename = './file.json'
with open(filename) as fp:
    jsonstuff = json.load(fp)

jsonstuff['key'] = 'tes'
with open(filename, "w") as fp:
    json.dump(jsonstuff, fp, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `file.truncate()` with no argument, it [truncates the file at the current location](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.truncate) (the end of file). Then when you call `file.seek(0)`, it moves to the start of the file and begins writing new data on top of the old data. If the new contents is shorter than the old contents (e.g., replacing a "test" string with "tes"), some of the old contents will be left over at the end. Here are several solutions:

- change the current `file.truncate()` to `file.truncate(0)`
- use `file.seek(0)` before writing to the file, then use `file.truncate()` immediately afterward or after you're finished writing data to the file
- use an `open(filename, 'r')` block to read the file, then use a separate `open(filename, 'w')` block to write back to the file (automatically replacing the full contents)